# Combobox: missing KeyDown when changing font of this control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I've modified combobox control (WinForms):
when nothing selected (in my code it's `item[0]`), then I set `combobox.Font` to *Italic* and *grey* color, but if any other item selected then I set `combobox.Font` to *Regular* and *black* color.

The problem is: when "nothing selected" and I begin typing, for example, I press key "s" then I expecting this behavior:

1) changing color to black and font to Regular.

2) erasing text "company name..." and pasting "s" to `combobox.Text` (automatic)

But I see only first, looks like after changing font `KeyDown` event is disappeared and it not pasting anything to combobox.Text....

The same happened when I try to change combobox items by keys Up and Down.

Here is the code:

```
    private void comboBoxFirmsFilterName_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBoxFirmsFilterName.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            comboBoxFirmsFilterName.Font = new Font(comboBoxFirmsFilterName.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
            comboBoxFirmsFilterName.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(64,64,64);
        }
        else
        {
            comboBoxFirmsFilterName.Font = regularFont;
            comboBoxFirmsFilterName.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        }
    }



    private void comboBoxFirmsFilterName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBoxFirmsFilterName.Font.Italic == true)
        {
            comboBoxFirmsFilterName.Font = regularFont;
            comboBoxFirmsFilterName.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should -1 not 0. 0 is the beginning of your index

Comment: thank you dan, but you are wrong because index[0] in my program is nothing is selected. Look: I have these items in combobox: "company name...", "first", "second", "third", .... So "company name..." mean that you should select anything. "company name..." drawn by italic font. But when you select something then this selected item drawn by regular font.